# Embedding Cordova + Crosswalk in an Android Studio Native Project

Tags: android, cordova, webview, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

As might you know, in an advanced scenario, you can [embed a Cordova WebView in an Android Native Project](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/webview.html), and then you can have a SystemWebView with applied cordova magic in one of your Android native project *activities*.

The same thing is available on Crosswalk. You can [embed a Crosswalk WebView in and Android Native Project](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/embedding_crosswalk.html), and then you can have an up-to-date chromium WebView instead of the old default SystemWebView which helps you to use more recent web technologies in your app.

There is a way to combine a Crosswalk WebView in a Cordova Project (A **standalone** Cordova project). It's easy as adding `cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` plugin to your Cordova project. Then you can have all the Cordova functionalities beside having the latest web standards.

I'm planning to use an **embedded** Cordova WebView using a Crosswalk Web View instead of default SystemWebView **in an Android Native Project** on Android Studio.

All of the guides I found so far are based on the scenario of adding just a cordova WebView to a native project. I have not found anything about using embedded Cordova with Crosswalk on a native project anywhere on the web.

Any ideas?